# What are the equivalents for DesignTimeVisibleAttribute and ToolBoxItemAttribute in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, design-time, toolbox

What are the equivalents for DesignTimeVisibleAttribute and ToolBoxItemAttribute in WP7?

We can use those two attributes to show/hide a certain control in design time, but the WP7's FCL does not include them.

What is the alternative solution?

Thanks

*In short terms: how to hide a WP7 custom control from the toolbox of Visual Studio??*

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, or you have to use attributes, but you can simply click on the `Hide` icon next to your control in the `Objects and Timeline` window. `DesignTimeVisibleAttribute` is a SL4 feature.

Comment: thanks, but I need to hide it in the designer of  Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IProvideAttributeTable

AttributeTableBuilder

ProvideMetadataAttribute

Just search for these three classes, that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting this code in the constructor of your custom control:

```
if (DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
{
    this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I should have made it clearer, sorry. I meant to hide it in the "Tool Box Window" of Visual Studio.